# SharePoint Online - Link to Item - Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, list-item

is it possible to assign Link to Item to a Calculated Column in SharePoint Online? I have read a few solutions suggesting editing AllItems.aspx in SPD designer but the calculated column is not listed in the code

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online you can use column formatting.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

For something like creating a hyperlink this is perfect as you likely do not need to store the underlying value.

Answer (score 0):

You can `CONCATENATE` an `a tag`  at the `calculated column` formula

Something like this [Ref](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial)

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href="http://server/sitename/Page.aspx?PageTitle=",Title,">",Title,"</a>")
```

But you must use the available fields that listed when you build your formula. and unfortunately the `Link To Item` require `ID field` that is not available !

Check also @Danny answer at [Calculated column with ID removes ID number on update](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159962/calculated-column-with-id-removes-id-number-on-update)
, [URL in calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15554/url-in-calculated-column)

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: unfortunately no , I depend on the reference , let me check it and if it is not worked I will update/delete it , thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman

Comment: ID doesn't always do what you want, See the answer at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159962/calculated-column-with-id-removes-id-number-on-update

Comment: you are right so let me update it, many thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman for this information