# Online - Hyperlink in calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I'm using SharePoint online and I've followed this solution [URL in calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15554/url-in-calculated-column) to create an hyperlink in a calculated column.

This is the formula I'm using:

```
="<a target='_blank' href='https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/site/documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=MyField&FilterValue1="
 &[Name]
 &"'>See Data</a>"
```

I've also set the calculated column as Number.

But this is the result in my list:

[image]

Are solutions suggested in that post still working?

**== UPDATE June 27, 2017 ==**

Microsoft has disabled this functionality on June 13, 2017.

You can find other informations looking at this post: [June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f)

Comment: Please refer this once before trying anything. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
="<a target=_blank "      
&"href=""https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com/site/documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"
&"?FilterField1=MyField"
&"&FilterValue1="
&[Name]
&""">See Data</a>"
```

Explanation: [Make dynamic calculated column Formula URL open as modal](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174756/make-dynamic-calculated-column-formula-url-open-as-modal/174780#174780)

Comment: I used your formula, but SP still does not convert text to hyperlink

Comment: As documented this (unsupported) Microsoft trick only works for non-Text Fields; and only in Classic SharePoint, are you trying this on a Modern Experience? Include a screenshot of your output to you question

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to set to classic SharePoint and not the modern. Now it works!

Comment: Do you know if something has changed on SharePoint Online? Your formula is not working anymore and I see not rendered HTML.

Comment: **Yes, F!$!# Microsoft disabled everything on june 13 th.. search for their statement, there is also a Q/A here on SO with all details**

Answer (score 2):

your formula it's ok, under the Formula Box you need to change *"The data type returned from this formula"* as **number** by default is marked as *"single line text"*

Answer (score 2):

Format the column using JSON to create a link

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions

Comment: This is a great tip for SharePoint in Microsoft 365. Used it today!