# SharePoint 2013 Document Library Calculated Column behavior on search

Tags: document-library, jquery

So...

I have a calculated column for multi-lingual documents so that I can have the English and French titles usable in document library views.  I turned on Document IDs and use the following code:

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href='**Site**/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID="&[Document ID Value]&"'>"&[Title (French Translation)]&"</a>")
```

This solution works for default views.  However.  When you search within the document library using the embedded search, the Calculated column reverts to...

```
"<a href='**Site**/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID="&[Document ID Value]&"'>"&[Title (French Translation)]&"</a>"
```

Note the leading and ending double quotes.

Thus, SP doesnt render the link anymore and instead just shows the code for the link.

Question:

1. Is there a way to override the behaviour change?
2. Is there a Jquery solution that can just remove the double quotes around the code, thus forcing the browser to render the link correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found another solution for this in another post around Hyperlinks in Calculated Fields.  Here [Online - Hyperlink in calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211835/online-hyperlink-in-calculated-column)

It's not the main answer, but if you change the returned value type from Single Line Text to Number, it resolves the quotation issue when searching the library.  Lucky fix.  Hopefully this still works when we eventually transition to SP 365.